# Unpack multiple dictionaries as functional arguments without repeating double asterisk

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack, argument-unpacking

I use API with long name of argument parameters. Consequently, I create following dictionaries for most common combinations of values which are then unpacked in function calls.

```
a_T = {'API parameter a': True}
a_F = {'API parameter a': False} 
b_100 = {'API parameter b': 100}
b_0 = {'API parameter b': 0}
hello = {'API parameter c': 'hello'}
bye = {'API parameter d': 'goodbye'}    

myf(**a_T, **bye)
myf(**b_0)
myf(**a_F, **b_100, **hello, **bye)
```

Is there any way to avoid repeat double asterisk? The code becomes quite unreadable with many of these strange characters.

Once could then add this unpacking utility to myf:

```
myf(a_T, bye)
myf(b_0)
myf(a_F, b_100, hello, bye)
```

Comment: What are you gaining from `a = {'a': True}` compared to `a = True`?

Comment: @matszwecja Only some parameters are boolean, hence consistency.

Comment: How is `a = {'a': True}; b = {'b': 100}` more consistent than `a = True; b = 100`?

Comment: @matszwecja You are asking good questions. The issue is a can also be False or b can be smth else than 100.

Comment: I don't see how that is an issue

Comment: @Ch3steR After the edit it makes tiny bit more sense.

Comment: @matszwecja Yes. My guess is they are getting all these arguments from some API maybe?

Comment: @Ch3steR good guess, there is indeed an API with clunky syntax.

Comment: If you're going to ask about aesthetics, please provide *way* more background for a specific answer

Comment: The whole idea of having 26 separately named dicts stinks to high heaven in the first place, so it seems a bit out of place to ask about a couple of extra characters

Comment: @MadPhysicist added more background. Apologies.

Comment: How do you determine which options to select? Surely you're mapping user input to this mess somehow?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The dictionary names are self-explanatory. Most API arguments are strings, I use arguments like `**west` or `**africa` instead of `side = 'west'` or `continent = 'Africa'`.

Comment: How do you decide whether to select `a_T` or `a_F`? Sounds like you just added an additional, possibly unnecessary or inefficient, layer of indirection there

Comment: @aeiou If that really is something as simple as `continent = 'Africa'` then I would say that obfuscating your code with things like `**africa` makes the code much less clean, harder to read and more error-prone.

Comment: @MadPhysicist interesting point. There is around 10 arguments I use 100 times. The API argument name is very long, hence intention to shorten it. The shortened version is self-explanatory, no one will need to memorize the 10 assignments to understand what's going on.

Comment: @matszwecja Good point about obfuscation, one will need to understand these arguments are unpacked somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use `|` for Python 3.9+ to combine all the dictionaries then send unpacked version.

```py
def fun(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

>>> fun(**a_F| b_100| hello| bye)
{'API parameter a': False, 'API parameter b': 100, 'API parameter c': 'hello', 'API parameter d': 'goodbye'}
```

Or just use `*args` and pass multiple dictionaries:

```py
def fun(*args):
    print(args)
    
>>> fun(a_F,b_100,hello,bye)
({'API parameter a': False}, {'API parameter b': 100}, {'API parameter c': 'hello'}, {'API parameter d': 'goodbye'})
```

Another solution is to use Python decorator and take care of ugly part inside the decorator function:

```py
def decorator(fun):
    def wrapper(*args):
        from functools import reduce
        kwargs = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, args)
        return fun(**kwargs)
    return wrapper
@decorator
def main_fun(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    

>>> main_fun(a_F,b_100,hello,z)
{'API parameter a': False, 'API parameter b': 100, 'API parameter c': 'hello', 'parameter 4': 'goodbye'}
```

Comment: @Ch3steR, yes I'm doing that

Comment: Combining dictionaries with `|` seems like a most sane idea given described use-case. One thing to keep in mind that it will silently ignore repeated parameters and only use last one.

Comment: @matszwecja, do you see any difference in passing `**kwargs` with different values for same key?

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1):

To unpack a series of dicts, use `dict.update`, or a nested comprehension:

```
def myf(*dicts):
    merged = {k: v for d in dicts for k, v in d.items()}
    # do stuff to merged
```

OR

```
def myf(*dicts):
    merged = {}
    for d in dicts:
        merged.update(d)
```